# Trouble printing a pseudo-multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print a pseudo-multidimensional array(don't ask why XD), but for some reason when i do this

```
#include <iostream>

#define Row_sz 3
#define Col_sz 4

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int row, col;
    int arr[Row_sz*Col_sz];

    cout<<"Printing a multi-dimensional array."<<endl;
    do{
        cout<<"Enter the number of rows: "<<endl;
        cin>>row;
    }while(row>Row_sz||row<0);
    do{
        cout<<"Enter the number of columns: "<<endl;
        cin>>col;
    }while(col>Col_sz||col<0);

    for (int x=0;x<row;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<col;y++){
            cout<<"Enter the value: "<<endl;
            cin>>arr[x*y];
        }

    }
    cout<<"The array matrix: "<<endl;
    for (int x=0;x<row;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<col;y++){
            cout<<arr[x*y]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

if I enter for example :5,4,3,2,1,6,7,8,9,11,12,13 I get

```
                                                         9 9 9 9
                                                         9 6 11 8
                                                         9 11 12 13
```

Instead of  :

```
                                                 5 4 3 2
                                                 1 6 7 8
                                                 9 11 12 13
```

or something like that.

Comment: word of advice from old programmer ... for 2d arrays, it is best to describe the data as rows and colums, OR x and y, but pick one. x is typically a horizontal dimension, while row is a vertical dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
 x*y
```

with

```
x*Col_sz+y
```

The * operator is multiplication.  Your array is 12 elements long. You want to fill in elements 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 ... 11. If you look at what `x*y` produces, you'll see that isn't what you want.